# Get translatable text from an external source into catalog

Tags: python, jinja2, python-babel

Possibly i am overlooking an obvious solution or thinking the wrong way...

I have a limited amount of text, words in a database, that I want to display translated to users in a flask/jinja/babel webapp. eg. "running" is a possible value of an "activity" column and that should be "laufen" for my german users.

Words in templates and code are extracted and put into the catalog, but how do i get *additional* words into the catalog? Is there a simple text file extractor?

The only thing i could think of is, just create a .py file and put lots of _('...') lines in them, but that feels just wrong... is it?

Comment: Are these words in the database defined as enums?

Comment: Yes, but don't limit yourself to enums or databases for that matter.

Another scenario might be an external system, maybe sending JSON to my system, with certain words, that i need translated, which *never* appear in *my* code, but only in the incoming messages.

I *know* those words from let's say the API specs, but I want to avoid putting them in my code as `_('word')`, just to be picked up by gettext.

I guess I'll just use a pain text file with a word per line and write my own extraction function for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a messages.txt with my "words" like gettext function calls:

```
_('cycling')
_('running')
```

and added it to my babel.cfg as python source:

```
[python: messages.txt]
```

plain, simple, stupid, but works.

Answer (score 2):

First, start with http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/4/.

Secondly, you need to store these 'limited' values as integers or enums in database and then create the lookup table for all these enums in code (so Babel knows about them):

```
i18n_val = {0: _('running'), ...}
# Or multi-level dict with different categories:
i18n_all = {
  'activity': {
     0: _('running'), ...
  'foo': {
     0: _('bar..'), ...
  }
}
```

And accessing the translated string from template is now as simple as:

```
{{ i18n_val[obj.activity] }}
{{ i18n_all['activity'][obj.activity] }}
```

In order to make the `i18n_val` and `i18n_all` variables available for all the templates, just register them with [context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors).

Comment: That second part is the one I have a problem with. I do not want to take all that text from the database and copy it somewhere in code by hand.

That last bit, I actually solved by using a "|trans" filter, that looks up translations.